# How to access structure members via the Octave C++ API?

Tags: c++, octave

Imagine an Octave function whose return value is a structure, it gives back something like

```
function info = mkStruct(arguments)
    % ...
  info.int = 55; % an integer
  info.str = 'Hi World!'; % a string
    % ...maybe more members
end  % function mkStruct
```

Now you want to use this `mkStruct` function inside a C++ program and access members of its returned structure. In the documentation describing [octave_value_list](http://octave.org/doxygen/4.1/d6/db6/classoctave__value__list.html#af7bacefc87aa00f4650b26e8161dd054) or [octave_value](http://octave.org/doxygen/4.1/d/d35/classoctave__value.html) I cannot find a hint (or I missed something).  The appendix ("Standalone Programs") of the Octave manual shows the general approach with

```
octave_value_list in;
  % Initialise $in...
octave_value_list out = feval("mkStruct", in);
```

But then...? I tried this

```
std::cout << "1. -> Int: " << out(0).int_value() << std::endl;
std::cout << "2. -> Str: " << out(1).string_value() << std::endl;
```

to get the value of the, say, first two members of the `info` structure, but after compilation (using `mkoctfile --link-stand-alone`) the program told me

```
error: octave_base_value::double_value (): wrong type argument 'scalar struct'
error: octave_base_value::int_value (): wrong type argument 'scalar struct'
error: octave_base_value::convert_to_str_internal (): wrong type argument '<unknown type>'
```

How can one access the individual members of a struct?